# Is It Possible to scene access from one file to another file in ROKU?

Tags: roku, brightscript

I create two files using bright script. Both extend in a scene so I access the second file in one file. But isn't work.

and I use one file for extend scene and another file for group It's working By below code.

```
m.keypanel = m.panelset.createChild("KeyboardDialogExample")
```

Is there any way to access it?

**Edited Post:**
[image]

I maintain Focus in Up or Down key. It's working and if stay email focus then I open dialog Box to press Ok. But Giving This error. I used separately It's Successfully Work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, what is happening in the code, you are creating a "KeyboardDialogExample" child in init() function, its fine. Problem is with setting the focus for that child. Basically init() function is called immediately after parsing the respective xml file, and is used to cache Nodes and setting field observers. So this function should not be used to setfocus on another component. Second thing Group node by default is not focusable. It can be made focusable, but almost all the time it is not required, because same functionality can be achieved in another easier way. Below are my suggestions for your requirement---

1. First replace

`m.keypanel = m.panelset.createChild("KeyboardDialogExample")
 m.keypanel.setFocus(true)`

with

```
m.keypanel = CreateObject("roSGNode", "KeyboardDialogExample")
m.keypannel.visible = false
m.top.appendChild(m.keypanel)
```

Its a recommended way to access other components.

2. Now set visibility to true,  on the whichever keypress event you want as-
   `m.keypannel.visible = true`
3. Add visibility observer in init()  function of "KeyboardDialogExample" as--

   `m.top.observeField("visible", "actionsToBePerformedOnVisibilityChange")`

create a function with the the name "actionsToBePerformedOnVisibilityChange' (or whatever name you want to keep, change it in observeField line as well), and add the code whatever actions you want to perform on visibility of that group.

```
function actionsToBePerformedOnVisibilityChange()
    if m.top.visible = true
     'add the action code here. 
    end if
end function
```

4. If you want to come back from "KeyboardDialogExample" to previous, just make the

   `m.keypannel.visible = false`

on the whichever keypress event you want and set the focus some field of main scene.

Try to code like this. after that you can hop between two files.

(**Note:-** You may be wondered, why we are setting visibility true and false repetitily. This is because observers generally work when there is change in value from previous one. For example, in above code, if we will not set the visibility of "keyboaddialogexample" to false in init() function of main scene, it will not observe the value when we will change it to true, because by default its true.)
Hope, I answered what you was looking.

Comment: Thank you, your 3rd point is I write code on KetboardDialogExample file onkeyevent code transfer to actionsToBePerformedOnVisibilityChange.

Comment: it should work, you just need to handle properly. May be you are missing something. If you want you can share the complete code, and make a document of your requirement (like navigations from where to where, required focus objects etc.). Tomorrow, I will try to look into it.

Comment: Sorry, My mistake It's Working.

Comment: @NikunjChaklasiya, thats great.

Comment: I maintain Focus Successfully. But Steel one issue Like previous I Edit my Post and add one error image.

Comment: @NikunjChaklasiya, error is selfexplanatory. You can not set "buttonSelected" observer for your m.top.dialog. Your "m.top.dialog" node does not support this interface.

Comment: Sorry, is it little Bit Confusing. I read Data Scoping and component Scop. But IS there any way to make it Global. I tried m.top replace to m.global but Still give same error.'

Comment: There is nothnig like global, except globalAA that is used to store and fetch values globally. You can access the objects of a component only by creating objects in other components. This is the only way to access the objects of other components.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's posible,
In .xml file of your m.keypanel(I see xml file of that component is named probably "KeyboardDialogExample"), expose your a value to the interface, something like this:

```
<interface>
    <field id="valueforuri" type="string" />
<interface>
```

Now you can just call m.keypanel.valueforuri = "www.google.com" from Your file where You initially created the m.keypanel component.
You can also send a function to be triggered in m.keypanel from another file/component.
Please check the [link](https://dev.to/umitic/how-to-define-a-function-in-component-interface-on-rokubrightscriptscenegraph-dff) to see how You can do this.

Comment: I create a one xml and brs for common simply two text box and two buttons and I find in init(). and I extend Group its work find like my question. But Its nothing to display I extend task or scene in another file. I not use `m.keypanel("KeyboardDialogExample")` in my XML is it required?

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure if I understood it correctly. Can You please post the code somewhere so I can check it and try to give You more specific answer? Thanks! :-)
p.s I have also edited my answer a little bit to avoid confusion.

Comment: https://github.com/chaklasiyanikunj/KeyboardDialogExample/tree/master here I upload all 3 file. I call  `m.keypanel = m.panelset.createChild("KeyboardDialogExample")` is panelset.brs init().

Comment: Ok, got it. Now what You really would like to do with m.keypanel? Can You be more specific than: "Is It Possible to scene access from one file to another file?" What's the specific goal You would like to achieve?

Comment: @U. Mitic I press any key in panelSet.brs file to open a keyboarddialogexample file functionality. and access all function or value.

Comment: I tried to perform Simple Navigation between both files.

Comment: Hmm...This is what I assume from the code: When You do this m.keypanel.setFocus(true) - You gave focus to the m.keypanel component so in that case onKeyEvent() function inside m.keypanel component will be the first that will try to handle remote button selection. I see You have some logic inside that function in m.keypanel that will, in some cases return handled = true. If that function returns true, then the button press won't be picked up by onKeyEvent() function in the Scene(PanelSet.brs) and You will not be able to set visible = false on m.keypanel from the PanelSet.brs.

Comment: Ok, I Got It. Thank you. any other way to instead of visible = false or seFocus(false) in Scene(panel.brs).